# AS3 Scale parent mc's center to child mc's center

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, scale

The following code centers the parent clip "mapcontainer.themap" on the state Georgia on load. However, when i try to scale mapcontainer.themap, it doesnt scale around Georgia's center. How do i keep Georgia in the center when scaling?

```
//This sets the parent clip so it's centered on the child "georgia" clip on load
var yValue:Number = mapcontainer.themap.georgia.y;
var xValue:Number = mapcontainer.themap.georgia.x;
var xDiff:Number = mapcontainer.themap.width/2;
var yDiff:Number = mapcontainer.themap.height/2;
if (xDiff > stage.stageWidth/2 || yDiff > stage.stageHeight/2) {
    xValue = -xValue;
    yValue = -yValue;
}
mapcontainer.themap.x = xValue;
mapcontainer.themap.y = yValue;

//This line?
mapcontainer.themap.scaleX = mapcontainer.themap.scaleY = 2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function derived from [here](http://timwhitlock.info/blog/2008/04/scale-rotate-around-an-arbitrary-centre/)

```
protected function scaleAround(objectToScale:DisplayObject, scalePoint:Point, scaleAmount:Number ):void {
    // scaling will be done relatively
    var relScaleX:Number = scaleAmount / objectToScale.scaleX;
    var relScaleY:Number = scaleAmount / objectToScale.scaleY;
    // map vector to centre point within parent scope

    scalePoint = objectToScale.localToGlobal( scalePoint );
    scalePoint = objectToScale.parent.globalToLocal( scalePoint );
    // current registered postion AB
    var AB:Point = new Point( objectToScale.x, objectToScale.y );
    // CB = AB - scalePoint, objectToScale vector that will scale as it runs from the centre
    var CB:Point = AB.subtract( scalePoint );
    CB.x *= relScaleX;
    CB.y *= relScaleY;
    // recaulate AB, objectToScale will be the adjusted position for the clip
    AB = scalePoint.add( CB );
    // set actual properties
    objectToScale.scaleX *= relScaleX;
    objectToScale.scaleY *= relScaleY;
    objectToScale.x = AB.x;
    objectToScale.y = AB.y;
}
```

So for your scenario, you could do this:

```
scaleAround(mapcontainer.themap,new Point(mapcontainer.themap.georgia.x,mapcontainer.themap.georgia.y),2)
```

Comment: Hi, all the clips have their registration points in the center

Comment: Ahh, I see what your doing now. Pardon my answering too quickly.  I'll update in a few minutes.  You're wanting to zoom in to a specific point on your map, not the center of the map.

Comment: Do you need to have your registration points centered?  Or were only doing that to make this easier?

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly - I've been trying to find this all day, good job!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17087/discussion-between-user1342133-and-londondrugs-mediaservices)