# Zoom to and from point

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, zooming, scale

I'm trying to zoom a DisplayObject into a certain point. I figured it would be easy, but I've spent a day now trying to figure it out.

Basically, I think this *should* work. Emphasis on should.

```
//newPoint is the point being centered. There is no initial scaling, so I do not need to compensate for that (yet)
//scale is the zoom level
//container is the parent of the obj
//obj is the object being scaled/panned
var p:Point = new Point(
    ( this.container.width - this.obj.width * scale + newPoint.x * scale ) / 2, 
    ( this.container.height - this.obj.height * scale + newPoint.y * scale ) / 2 
);

this.obj.scaleX = this.obj.scaleY = scale;
this.obj.x = p.x;
this.obj.y = p.y;
```

It centers the point if scale is 1, but it gets further and further away from center as you increase the scale. I've tried dozens of different methods. [This method](https://gist.github.com/3092911), which I have seen on several sites, produced the same exact results. Anyone have any idea how to get this to work?

**EDIT 10-1-12**:
As a followup, I took the [code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12571958/as3-scale-parent-mcs-center-to-child-mcs-center/12572155#12572155) that LondonDrugs_MediaServices provided as a basis for my original issue. I needed to be able to zoom to a specific point at a specific scale relative to the unscaled image (think how Google Maps zooms to a specific location). To do this, I had to center my image on the point before running the translation code. I've posted the additional code below. For other uses (pinch to zoom, scrolling, and double click), I used the code provided by Vesper, which worked quite well.

```
//obj is the object being translated
//container is its parent
//x and y are the coordinates to be zoomed to, in untranslated scaling
//obj.scaleX and obj.scaleY are always identical in my class, so there is no need to account for that


//calculates current center point, with scaling
var center:Point = new Point( ( this.container.width - this.obj.width * this.obj.scaleX ) / 2, ( this.container.height - this.obj.height * this.obj.scaleX ) / 2 );

//calulcates the distance from center the point is, with scaling
var distanceFromCenter:Point = new Point( this.obj.width * this.obj.scaleX / 2 - x * this.obj.scaleX, this.obj.height * this.obj.scaleX / 2 - y * this.obj.scaleX );

//center the object on that specific point
this.obj.x = center.x + distanceFromCenter.x;
this.obj.y = center.y + distanceFromCenter.y;
```

Comment: Try looking at my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12571958/as3-scale-parent-mcs-center-to-child-mcs-center/12572155#12572155

Comment: Leads to precisely the same issue I have had with every other method I've attempted. Only the actual center of the image will center, everything else is exponentially off. Look here. http://imgur.com/M1kBJ Image is 700x525, parent is the stage which is 1024x768. Thanks for the help regardless, though.

Comment: Actually... I'm looking at it right now, and both this code snippet and the snippet that Vesper provided are positioning the point (200,200) at... (200,200). They're not centering it on the screen, but placing it at (200,200) on the screen. Very interesting. I might be able to rework this now.

Comment: I'm 99% positive the link I shared (and answer associated with the link) will do what you want.  You just have to keep in mind the Point you pass to the function is relative to the object your scaling

Comment: Yes. I had to modify the point a bit, but I got it to work using both your and Vesper's methods. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @LondonDrugs_MediaServices I added the code I needed to accomplish everything I needed to my OP, if you're interested. Again, thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var mat:Matrix=new Matrix();
mat.translate(-p.x,-p.y);
mat.scale(desiredScale,desiredScale);
mat.translate(p.x,p.y);
yourObject.transform.matrix=mat;
```

The core point is that scaling is done around (0,0), but you can do it with matrix that describes affine transformations. You first make an empty matrix (that is, a matrix that doesn't transform), then apply a set of transformations to it. First, place a desired point at (0,0) by translating by -1*coordinates, then scale, then translate back.

Comment: This is close, but it still isn't accurate. As you can see in this screenshot ( http://imgur.com/ZeEhv ), the 200x200 mark is not quite centered. It looks like only the very center of the image will be centered when the coordinates are entered. I'm looking at using this class on DisplayObjects that are thousands of pixels in both width and height, so close just is not going to cut it here. Thanks for the help, though.

Comment: Well, you need to use more than one transformation, this means. I was writing the code that zooms at a certain point, making it remain in place. In order for you to zoom at a certain point and move it into the center, you either first move then zoom at center, or first zoom in place and move to center.

Comment: Yes. I just realized what your code did (see the last comment on my OP). I am working on adjusting the code to fit my needs now. But this is actually great. I can use this for mouse wheel/pinch zoom. I just need to be able to call a point to be zoomed and its zoom level and have it appear centered on the screen. (Imagine Google Maps functionality). Once I get this working, I'll accept your answer. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

hie guys....
thank's your comments...
i found the answer...
code :

gambar.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_ZOOM , onZoom);
    function onZoom(event:TransformGestureEvent):void {

```
    var locX:Number=event.localX;

    var locY:Number=event.localY;

    var stX:Number=event.stageX;

    var stY:Number=event.stageY;

    var prevScaleX:Number=gambar.scaleX;

    var prevScaleY:Number=gambar.scaleY;

    var mat:Matrix;

    var externalPoint=new Point(stX,stY);

    var internalPoint=new Point(locX,locY);

    gambar.scaleX *= event.scaleX;

    gambar.scaleY *= event.scaleY;

     if(event.scaleX>1 && gambar.scaleX>6){

         gambar.scaleX=prevScaleX;

         gambar.scaleY=prevScaleY;

       }

     if(event.scaleY>1 && gambar.scaleY>6){

         gambar.scaleX=prevScaleX;

         gambar.scaleY=prevScaleY;

       } 

      if(event.scaleX<1 && gambar.scaleX<0.8){

         gambar.scaleX=prevScaleX;

         gambar.scaleY=prevScaleY;

       }

     if(event.scaleY<1 && gambar.scaleY<0.8){

         gambar.scaleX=prevScaleX;

         gambar.scaleY=prevScaleY;

       }  

     mat=gambar.transform.matrix.clone();

     MatrixTransformer.matchInternalPointWithExternal(mat,internalPoint,externalPoint);

     gambar.transform.matrix=mat;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The matrix answer is absolutely correct, but if you happen to be a Club GreenSock member you can get some nice functionality with very simple code with the TransformAroundPointPlugin

http://www.greensock.com/as/docs/tween/com/greensock/plugins/TransformAroundPointPlugin.html

You can see an example in the plugin explorer here:
http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/#plugins

I use this to tween all my zooms and have much better performance than when I tried to do this manually. IMO the whole library is worth it's weight in gold (and no I have no connection other than liking the library). If you need any of the other features I'd look into it. It also has the ThrowProps plugin  ( http://www.greensock.com/throwprops/ )which is very important if you are going to have a bounding box on mobile that you want to have a smooth return into the boundaries.

Answer (score -1):

Set obj.x to -p.x and obj.y to -p.y, set the container scaleX and scaleY to the desired value and add p.x to the container x and p.y to the container y. Done!

Comment: I can't change anything on the container. The requirement of this class is that you pass in the object and container during instantiation and that is all you have to do. Changing the container scale in Flex (another requirement. It has to be usable in both Flex and standard AS3 projects) would cause sizing issues with its siblings