# AS3 zooming in and out where mouse clicked not at registration

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, zooming

I am trying to have a masked mouse panned image zoom in and out with a click and a double click mouse event. I got the image to zoom but it always zooms in on the left edge registration point, not where I click. I have absolutely no idea how to code this and have spent the whole day on the internet trying to figure it out with no luck. I am hoping someone can help me to figure this out!

```
import com.greensock.*;//Greensock Tweening Platform.

//Variables
var percX:Number;
var percY:Number;
var destX:Number;
var destY:Number;

//Image panned and masked
this.mask = mask_mc;
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,mousemove);
function mousemove(e:MouseEvent) {
    if (mask_mc.hitTestPoint(stage.mouseX,stage.mouseY,false)) {
        if (imgLoader.width>mask_mc.width) {//Avoids Scrolling if image is under mask area width
            percX = mask_mc.mouseX/mask_mc.width;
        }
        if (imgLoader.height>mask_mc.height) {//Avoids Scrolling if image is under mask area height
            percY = mask_mc.mouseY/mask_mc.height;
        }
        destX = -(imgLoader.width-mask_mc.width)*percX;
        destY = -(imgLoader.height-mask_mc.height)*percY;
        TweenMax.to(imgLoader,.5,{x:destX,y:destY});
    }
}
//Add listeners for the imgLoader movie clip.
imgLoader.doubleClickEnabled = true;  
imgLoader.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, increaseSize);
imgLoader.addEventListener(MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK, decreaseSize);

//This function increases the scale of the image
function increaseSize(event:MouseEvent):void{
TweenLite.to(imgLoader, 1, {scaleX:2, scaleY:2});
}

//This function decreases the scale of the image
function decreaseSize(event:MouseEvent):void{
TweenLite.to(imgLoader, 1, {scaleX:1, scaleY:1});
}
```

Comment: you need to translate scale then translate, so you move the point the person clicked up and to the left until it "lands" at the registration point, then you scale then you slide back (all out of view).  See some more details here: http://www.flashandmath.com/howtos/rotation/index.html <-- looks like this offers a couple of methods I wasn't aware of that handle this internally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is derived from [here](http://timwhitlock.info/blog/2008/04/scale-rotate-around-an-arbitrary-centre/)

Add this function:

```
function scaleAroundMouse(objectToScale:DisplayObject, scaleAmount:Number, bounds:Rectangle = null, onComplete:Function = null):TweenLite {
    // scaling will be done relatively
    var relScaleX:Number = scaleAmount / objectToScale.scaleX;
    var relScaleY:Number = scaleAmount / objectToScale.scaleY;
    // map vector to centre point within parent scope

    var scalePoint:Point = objectToScale.localToGlobal( new Point(objectToScale.mouseX, objectToScale.mouseY));
    scalePoint = objectToScale.parent.globalToLocal( scalePoint );
    // current registered postion AB
    var AB:Point = new Point( objectToScale.x, objectToScale.y );
    // CB = AB - scalePoint, objectToScale vector that will scale as it runs from the centre
    var CB:Point = AB.subtract( scalePoint );
    CB.x *= relScaleX;
    CB.y *= relScaleY;
    // recaulate AB, objectToScale will be the adjusted position for the clip
    AB = scalePoint.add( CB );
    // set actual properties

    if(bounds){
     var limits:Rectangle = new Rectangle(
        bounds.x + (bounds.width - (objectToScale.width * relScaleX)),
        bounds.y + (bounds.height - (objectToScale.height * relScaleY)),
        (objectToScale.width * relScaleX) - bounds.width,
        (objectToScale.height * relScaleY) - bounds.height
     );

     if(AB.x < limits.x) AB.x = limits.x;
     if(AB.x > limits.x + limits.width) AB.x = limits.x + limits.width;
     if(AB.y < limits.y) AB.y = limits.y;
     if(AB.y > limits.y + limits.height) AB.y = limits.y + limits.height;       
    }

    return TweenLite.to(objectToScale,1,{onComplete: onComplete, scaleX: scaleAmount, scaleY: scaleAmount, x: AB.x, y: AB.y);
}
```

Then update your sizing function to this:

```
function increaseSize(event:MouseEvent):void{
    stopMouseMove();
    scaleAroundMouse(imgLoader, 2, null, resumeMouseMove);
}

function decreaseSize(event:MouseEvent):void{
    stopMouseMove();
    scaleAroundMouse(imgLoader, 1, null, resumeMouseMove);
}

function stopMouseMove():void {
   stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,mousemove);
}

function resumeMouseMove():void {
   stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,mousemove);
}
```

I also added a bounds parameter to the function. This is useful if you never want the edges of you content to be visible within the mask.  So if you could use it by passing the bounds of your mask to the function:

```
scaleAroundMouse(imgLoader, 1, myMask.getBounds(this));
```

Answer (score 0):

This example uses zoom effect classes that may help achieve the zoom effect you are looking for http://graphics-geek.blogspot.com/2010/06/video-image-zoom-effect-in-flex-4.html.

Answer (score 0):

```
var mat:Matrix=new Matrix();
mat.translate(-p.x,-p.y);
mat.scale(desiredScale,desiredScale);
mat.translate(p.x,p.y);
yourObject.transform.matrix=mat;
```

That is taken from a question I posted about a month ago. You can see it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12649936/1515620). While I didn't end up going with that specific snippet (I actually went with a modified version of the script LondongDrugs_MediaServ posted), it will work and is much easier to understand and implement.