# MultiBitmap centering spirtes AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

The main code:

```
package  {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.net.URLVariables;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;
    import flash.geom.Point;
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.Bitmap;

    public class Init extends Sprite {

        var rects:Array,
        numRects:int = stage.stageWidth / _width,
        _width:Number = 20,
        _height:Number = 80,
        _rotation:int = 0,
        _vr:Number = 3;

        public function Init() {

            init();
        }

        function init():void
        {
            rects = new Array();
            var bitmap:BitmapData = new slider();
            var _point = new Point();
            for(var i:int = 0; i < numRects; i++)
            {
                var _rect = new Rectangle(i * _width, 0, _width, 80);
                var smallBD:BitmapData = new BitmapData(_width, 80);
                smallBD.copyPixels(bitmap, _rect, _point);
                //var d:Bitmap = new Bitmap(smallBD); 
                var rect:Rect = new Rect(smallBD, _width, _height);
                rect.x = i * _width + _width / 2;
                addChild(rect);
                rects.push(rect);
            }

            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
        }

        function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void
        {

            for(var i:int = 0; i < numRects; i++)
            {
                rects[i].rotationY += _vr;
            }

            _rotation += _vr;
            if(_rotation % 180 == 0)
            {
                removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
            }

        }


    }

}
```

this is the rect class:

```
package  {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;

    public class Rect extends Sprite {

        private var bitmap:BitmapData,
        _width:Number,
        _height:Number;
        public function Rect(bitmap:BitmapData, width:Number = 20, height:Number = 80) {

            this.bitmap = bitmap;
            this._width = width;
            this._height = height;
            init();
        }

        function init():void
        {
            graphics.beginBitmapFill(bitmap, null, true, true);

            graphics.drawRect(-_width / 2, 0, _width , _height);

            graphics.endFill();


        }

    }

}
```

I am dividing the imported image into pieces, and each piece adding to each rectangle sprite, so I am making a rotation effect, but the problem is that when I make it I'cant center the sprites, So i've make the `(-_width / 2)` - trick to center each sprite by x axis, and then adding to x position adding `_width / 2`, but I can't figure it out why the image are deformating, you can try this code by geting a 780 x 80 image
[image]

Comment: image added you can test it with this image by importing into flash library, and tell me what I am doing wrong

Comment: if you remove the -_width / 2 in the drawRect method AND  + _width / 2, it will work good, but the rotation will by in the left top corner, thats not good for me

Comment: What does deformatting mean?

Comment: it happens when i move the drawing rectangle by -10 pixels, i can't understand this moment, so what i want is to rotate each sprite from the center of it and the image position exactly inlet into to the stage sizes

Comment: you can try this code with this image and you will see what i am talking about

Comment: he's fighting with his transform center.  This is really easy in flex they have properties on Rects for that.  Can one of you that is familiar with this is Flash as3 give him a hand.  @Zecrow do a little google-ing on object transform centers... that tells the rotation where it should rotate around.

Comment: if you are using rotationY then maybe you need to adjust the perspective projection? `flash.geom.PerspectiveProjection`

Answer (score 0):

Well, seeing you employ `beginBitmapFill()` in order to make your rectangles, you are free to assign where will it be drawn. You seemingly need that your rectangle will be rotated around its center, instead of top left corner. You did good writing `-_width/2` as starting X, now you just have to write `-height/2` as starting Y.

```
graphics.drawRect(-_width / 2, -_height / 2, _width , _height);
```

This will make your drawn bitmap have its center at your sprite's (0,0) position, so that any rotation you apply will make the sprite turn around the center of its drawn rectangle.

In general, if you plain apply rotation to a display object, it always rotates around (0,0) of its own, so if you seek to compensate, either write transform matrices (several examples available at SO, say [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648161/zoom-to-and-from-point) ), or draw your sprite so that (0,0) is at the point you want to rotate around.